# How can I get latest comment from specific new?

Tags: sql

I have a table

```
News(newsId, text, date)
```

and

```
Comments(commentId, text, date, newsId)
```

and I need to select 10 newest news by date with a newest comment from each. So far I have this, how do I improve it and finish it?

```
  SELECT date, 
         newsId, 
         commentid, 
         date
    FROM News, 
         comments
ORDER BY date DESC
   LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: dbms name please

Comment: First, get rid of *cartesian join* of `News`  and `comments` tables

Comment: Do you want to get a *single* (newest) `comment` for each `news`? What if `news` doesn't have any comments yet?

Comment: Yes, single newest comment. Omit the intention if it does not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `row_number()` as:

```
select n.newsid, n.text, n.text, n.date, c.text as comment 
from news n left join
     (select c.*,
             row_number() over (partition by c.newsid order by date desc) as seqnum
      from comments c
     ) c
     on c.newsId = n.newsId and seqnum = 1
order by n.date desc
limit 10;
```

Note that this returns news items with no comments.  If you do not want those, then change the `left join` to an `inner join`.

Answer (score 0):

if your dbms support row_number then you can try like below

```
with cte as
(select *,row_number()over(partition by newsId order by date desc) rn
from News
), cte1 as
(
select newsId, text, date from cte where rn<=10
) select cte1.*,c.commentId,c.text as commnt from cte1 join Comments c on cte1.newsid=c.newsid
```

Answer (score 0):

For older DBMS subquery will useful :

```
select n.newsid, n.text, n.text, n.date, c.text as comment 
from news n inner join
     comments c
     on c.newsId = n.newsId
where c.date in (select c1.date 
                 from comments c1 
                 where c1.newsid = n.newsid 
                 order by c1.date desc
                 limit 10
                );
```

Howver, for newest version DBMS `row_number()` is a generic to do this.